# Accessing global var from child package

Tags: go

I am writing a small go application that has some global consts defined in main.go like below:

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/JackBracken/global/sub"
)

const AppName string = "global string"

func main() {
    sub.Run()
}
```

sub/sub.go

```
package sub

import "fmt"

func Run() {
    fmt.Println(AppName)
}
```

I'm pretty new to Go and would expect something like this to work, but `go build` throws the error `sub/sub.go:6: undefined: AppName`.

I know I can do something like creating a `globals` package, import it in `sub.go` and refer to my global variables with `globals.AppName` etc., but I'd like to know if it's possible my original way, or am I just completely misunderstanding scoping and packages?

Comment: You can't import a "main" package

Comment: @JimB I understand that much I think. Global variables are global only within the package they are defined in then? And to reference them from another package that package has to be imported? I guess I made the assumption that a sub-package be able to access its parent's global variables (but the more I read into it, the less the idea of a "sub-package" seems to make any sense).

Comment: Sub packages aren't even a thing in Go. Every package is distinct, even from packages in the directory they are a subdirectory of.  There's no implicit access there.  If it's in your package, you can use it innately.  If it's not in your package, even if it's in the parent directory, you still have to import it.  And unfortunately, you can't import `main` packages (except in a test file), so anything in `package main` is only access to that package, period.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot access symbols in the 'main' package anywhere else, for the simple reason that Go does not allow import loops.

If you need to access a variable in both 'main' and some other package, you'll need to move your variables elsewhere, to a package that both can access. So your 'globals' package is the right idea.